# iTextSharp unable to find text rotated at a specific angel

Tags: c#, .net, pdf-generation, itext

I am using the following class to find text position in pdf:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;

namespace PdfTextHighlighter.Code
{
public class RectAndText
{
    public iTextSharp.text.Rectangle Rect;
    public String Text;

    public RectAndText(iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect, String text)
    {
        this.Rect = rect;
        this.Text = text;
    }
}


public class MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy : LocationTextExtractionStrategy
{
    //Hold each coordinate
    public List<RectAndText> MyPoints = new List<RectAndText>();

    //The string that we're searching for
    public String TextToSearchFor { get; set; }

    //How to compare strings
    public System.Globalization.CompareOptions CompareOptions { get; set; }

    public MyLocationTextExtractionStrategy(String textToSearchFor,
        System.Globalization.CompareOptions compareOptions = System.Globalization.CompareOptions.None)
    {
        this.TextToSearchFor = textToSearchFor;
        this.CompareOptions = compareOptions;
    }

    //Automatically called for each chunk of text in the PDF
    public override void RenderText(TextRenderInfo renderInfo)
    {
        base.RenderText(renderInfo);

        //See if the current chunk contains the text
        var startPosition = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(
            renderInfo.GetText(), this.TextToSearchFor, this.CompareOptions);



        //If not found bail
        if (startPosition < 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (renderInfo.PdfString.ToString() != this.TextToSearchFor)
        {
            return;
        }

        //Grab the individual characters
        var chars =
            renderInfo.GetCharacterRenderInfos().Skip(startPosition).Take(this.TextToSearchFor.Length).ToList();



        //Grab the first and last character
        var firstChar = chars.First();
        var lastChar = chars.Last();


        //Get the bounding box for the chunk of text
        var bottomLeft = firstChar.GetDescentLine().GetStartPoint();
        var topRight = lastChar.GetAscentLine().GetEndPoint();

        //Create a rectangle from it
        var rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(
            bottomLeft[Vector.I1],
            bottomLeft[Vector.I2],
            topRight[Vector.I1],
            topRight[Vector.I2]
            );

        //Add this to our main collection
        this.MyPoints.Add(new RectAndText(rect, this.TextToSearchFor));
      }
     }
   }
```

It works very well with horizontal or vertical text. However it is unable to find text rotated at an angle. How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm surprised that your code *works great with text which is horizontal or vertical.* Your check `renderInfo.PdfString.ToString() != this.TextToSearchFor` expects the whole search text to be rendered at once, and it is very common (also in horizontal and vertical text) to have even words split up into separate chunks rendered separately.

Comment: Hi mkl, the text that I am searching for in the PDF is electronic component name and all of them are one chunk in pdf like "C100", "R501" & so on. Maybe that's why the code works.

Answer (score 0):

Current open source version of iTextSharp will not be able to do this. If you have a licence you can login to itext forums & ask them. I am using the same class as above for my project but in my case text is horizontal so I have not problems.